# Sub report to run of a value returned in the main report

Tags: reporting-services

I am struggling with adding a Subreport to my main report.

I have a main report we will call Supplier, which takes 2 parameters *DateFrom* & *DateTo*; this brings me back a list of suppliers with these columns *AccountID*, *Account*, *Name*.

Even though *AccountID* is returned in the initial dataset its not displayed in the report - what I want to do is be able to click on the *Account* field and get to a subreport of performance

This report needs 3 parameters - the *AccountID*, *DateFrom* and *DateTo* parameters from the initial dataset

I cant seem to add the subreport though, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create the SubReport as required as a separate RDL file.

Next, in the main Report, add a SubReport placeholder as required - based on your description this will be to a table that lists your *Accounts*:

[image]

Go to the SubReport properties and link the placeholder to the SubReport you've already created:

[image]

Finally, link the Parameters from the main Report to the SubReport:

[image]

You can see that *AccountID* will take the field in the table row, and *DateFrom* and *DateTo* will have the main Report parameters passed through.

This should be all linked up and ready to go.

Comment: Hi Ian, that was brilliant, my issue was that I wasn't putting my subreport within the dataset/table of the first report, hence I wasn't getting the AccountID for the sub, thanks again, Phil

Comment: You're welcome! If you find an answer helpful, please considering upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.